# proper use of awk, sort and uniq

Tags: awk, uniq

I am dealing with a large (500MB+) .csv file. I want to print out the unique values of a given column a page at a time for easy viewing.

```
awk F, '{print $}' sort | uniq
```

This yields a rapidly scrolling list that cuts off 75% of the values I am interested in.

Comment: You seem to have missed '|' before sort. `awk F, '{print $}' | sort | uniq`. Also, uniq's output may have more than one screenful. You may want to add '| more' to view it comfortably.

Comment: If only (*cough* `> a_file` *cough*) there was some way to capture the results to disk..

Comment: For paging I suggest to use `less`, or as suggested, direct the output to a file for manual inspection.

Answer (score 2):

Try below awk command, it will keep the original order to export the unique on #1 column (you can adjust to another column easily)

```sh
awk -F, '!a[$1]++' file
```

If you need to sort the result, then add the sort command after awk, which will save big time for you.

```sh
awk -F, '!a[$1]++' file |sort
```

Comment: Instead of pipe outside, I think you can do this, inside awk `awk -F, '!a[$1]++{print | "sort"}' file`

Comment: This does not bring any improvements. Piping the output to `sort` inside awk or outside does not make any difference and makes the "code" less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

x = column number

sort -r:

```
awk -F"," '{a[$x]++}END{for(i in a)b[j++]=i;n=asort(b);while(n>0)print b[n--]}' file
```

sort:

```
awk -F"," {a[$x]++}END{for(i in a)b[j++]=i;asort(b);while(k<=NR)print b[k++]}' file
```